# OpenSSL SSL_CTX conflict with QT sslErrors

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

After using "SSL_CTX * _sslctx = ..." in my project, the QT signals sslErrors are not executed. It just returns the error: "qt.network.ssl: Neither X509_STORE, nor SSL contains error list, handshake failure"

I don't intend to use QT to work with certificates, just OpenSSL because I use Libxml2. Using separate QT network and OpenSSL is returning this error when using SSL_CTX.

Does anyone know what must be done?

Comment: What is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is **windows** you should install [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Answer (score 0):

What I've found so far is that no class that has "SSL_CTX", can have connection to the QT class of the network that uses "sslErrors signals" in its project, this will give a problem. If you #include "class_with_ssl_clx", or inherit from a parent class that has "SSL_CTX", you will also have problems with signals.